# Free NavBar control for Open Source progect

Tags: wpf, navbar

For Open source project I Am looking for free NavBar control. 
I mean something like this. Please tell me the name or address of free NavBar controls.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make one on your own out of a tabcontrol.

There is a tutorial over on code project

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24106/Creating-an-Outlook-Navigation-Pane-by-Restyling-a